# Issue in Entity Query in SOLR

Tags: mysql, solr

I am trying to run the following query in data-config.xml and trying to import products. But I am getting the following error

> org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to >execute query: SELECT oh.tax_class_id as tax_class_id FROM oc_hsn oh >WHERE oh.hsn_code= Processing Document # 1

My query is as follows :

```
 <entity name="hsn_data"
   query="SELECT oh.tax_class_id as tax_class_id  
   FROM oc_hsn oh
         WHERE oh.hsn_code=${products.hsn_code}" 
 />
```

Here products.hsn_code is hsn_Code which is of VARCHAR(8) type.

It is not primary key for the table.

I dont know how to use this hsn_Code to process this query.

Is it like I can only use primary keys after WHERE clause in entity?
Please throw some light

My data-config is as follows :

```
 <entity name="products" transformer="RegexTransformer"
  query="SELECT 
  p.product_id as id,
  p.hsn_code as hsn_code, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pc.category_id) separator ',') as    category_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cd.name) separator ',') as categories,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pf.filter_id) separator ',') as filter_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(fd.name) separator ',') as filters,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(p2s.store_id) separator ',') as store_id
  FROM oc_product AS p
  LEFT JOIN oc_product_description AS pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_stock_status AS ss ON ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category AS pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_description AS cd ON cd.category_id = pc.category_id 
 LEFT JOIN oc_product_filter AS pf ON pf.product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description AS fd ON fd.filter_id = pf.filter_id 
 LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store AS p2s ON p2s.product_id = p.product_id
 GROUP BY p.product_id" 

 deltaImportQuery="SELECT 
  p.product_id as id,
  p.hsn_code as hsn_code, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pc.category_id) separator ',') as category_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cd.name) separator ',') as categories,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pf.filter_id) separator ',') as filter_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(fd.name) separator ',') as filters,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(p2s.store_id) separator ',') as store_id
  FROM oc_product AS p
  LEFT JOIN oc_product_description AS pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_stock_status AS ss ON ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category AS pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_description AS cd ON cd.category_id = pc.category_id 
 LEFT JOIN oc_product_filter AS pf ON pf.product_id = p.product_id
 LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description AS fd ON fd.filter_id = pf.filter_id 
 LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store AS p2s ON p2s.product_id = p.product_id   
 WHERE p.product_id='${products.id}'
 GROUP BY p.product_id"

 deltaQuery="
  SELECT p.product_id as id, p.date_modified , p.hsn_code as hsn_code
  FROM oc_product AS p
  WHERE p.date_modified > '${products.last_index_time}'" >

<entity name="hsn_data"
  query="SELECT oh.tax_class_id as tax_class_id  
         FROM oc_hsn oh
         WHERE oh.hsn_code=${products.hsn_code}" />

  <field column="id" sourceColName="id" />
  <field column="tax_class_id" sourceColName="tax_class_id"  />
  <field column="hsn_code" sourceColName="hsn_code"  />
  </entity>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Read out this link , it may help https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#A_shorter_data-config

Comment: Any specific details you wouldd like to give?

Comment: it's like products will be the root table having hsn_code as primary key 
and in your entity (data-config) products will be the root entity .
can you share the data-config you have ?

Comment: I have shared the data -config in post. please check

Comment: Also as I have mentioned, hsn_code is not primary key, product_id is the primary key of product table

Comment: You are using FULL Import ? and also where the main entity tag (name="products"  ) get's closed ?  after  <field column="hsn_code" sourceColName="hsn_code"  /> this line </entity>  ?

Comment: Apologies. I  have edited the code. Added </entity> This is FULL Import.